# Solaris backup old

Tags: backup, solaris

I have some old Solaris backups (to tape), I think v4, that I want to restore. I'm not sure what the format is. The binary has 1024 blocks, each block starts with 00 00 00 01,02,03,04,05 or 06 and then a 4 byte epoch date. I've figured out the headers:
00 00 00 01 - Backup Header
00 00 00 02 - Regular file content
00 00 00 04 - File continuation
00 00 00 05 - End of backup
00 00 00 03 & 06 - Some type of mask with lots of FF FF FF ...
Ideally I would love to get a specification for this format, but at least it would be good to know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Most old tape backups are:

tar

cpio

dump/restore

If you have some of the data written on disk, you could determine the format using the file command.

$ file {data}

{data}: new-fs dump file (big endian), Previous dump Mon Oct 28 17:57:36 2019, This dump Wed Dec 31 16:00:00 1969, Volume 1, Level zero, type: tape header, Label none, Filesystem /, Device /dev/dsk/c1t1d0s0, Host myhostname, Flags 1

$ file {data}

{data}:    USTAR tar archive

If I had to venture a guess I would say the data is dump format.

Remember also that a tape may have multiple data streams separated by EOF markers. You  may need to use the mt command to get to the data.

$ mt fsf 1

Will move past the next EOF marker.

Comment: The tapes have a single backup file. The File command gives me "new-fs dump file", so it seems to be conclusive, thanks for the tip.